# How to get the numerical answer to NIntegrate[t^(1/3)-t^(2/3),{t,-1,0}] in Reals only

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I need to integrate the expression (t^(1/3)-t^(2/3)) from t=-1 to t=0, using Mathematica version 7, and I want the real answer only.  How do I do this?  I am not sure whether I use NIntegrate or if it must be done with Integrate and somehow later evaluate it.  Obviously I want whichever should be used restricted to Reals only.  I’ve looked at Assumptions, Assuming, Element, and many other things, but I am totally a beginner, and I can’t get anything to work.  I have spent many hours trying to do this.  Would you give me the code to do it?  (Please assume I know little to nothing.)

Copyable code:

```
NIntegrate[t^(1/3)-t^(2/3), {t,-1,0}]
```

Comment: Have you seen `Surd` ?

Comment: It appears you want `Integrate[Surd[t, 3] - Surd[t^2, 3], {t, -1, 0}]`.

Comment: Note that `Surd` was introduced in V9. The OP is specifically asking about V7.

Comment: Here's a way to rewrite an integrand to use real powers, with the tacit assumption that the base of `Power` is always real: `newintegrand = 
 integrand /. Power[b_, x_Rational] /; OddQ@Denominator@x :> Simplify[Sign[b]^Numerator[x], b \[Element] Reals && b != 0] Power[Abs[b], x]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

[`Surd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) was introduced in v9.

```
int = Integrate[Surd[t, 3] - Surd[t^2, 3], {t, -1, 0}]

(* -(27/20) *)

int // N

(* -1.35 *)
```

**For earlier versions**,

```
surd[x_, n_Integer?OddQ] := Sign[x]*Abs[x]^(1/n)

surd[x_?Positive, n_Integer?EvenQ] := x^(1/n)

int2 = Integrate[surd[t, 3] - surd[t^2, 3], {t, -1, 0}]

(* -(27/20) *)

Plot[surd[t, 3] - surd[t^2, 3], {t, -1, 0},
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]